# How to Add link to message

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was trying to make a notification with line notify but I dont know how to insert a command that puts a link from my google sheet to the message of the notification

```html
 // Line Notify
function onFormSubmit() {

var form = FormApp.openById('1ELczQ-uW1mauQrHFBpHK2pQnCCkvPf_4Nq-DPqM4nMw');
var fRes = form.getResponses();

var formResponse = fRes[fRes.length - 1];
var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
var link = shape.getLink();
            if (link != null && link.getLinkType() == SlidesApp.LinkType.URL) {
            Logger.log('Shape has link to URL: ' + link.getUrl());
}

var msg = 'Electric Forklift Incentive'
 + ' \n' + itemResponses[5].getItem().getTitle() + ': ' + itemResponses[5].getResponse()
 + ' \n' + itemResponses[0].getItem().getTitle() + ': ' + itemResponses[0].getResponse()
 + ' \n' + itemResponses[1].getItem().getTitle() + ': ' + itemResponses[1].getResponse() 
 + ' \n' + itemResponses[2].getItem().getTitle() + ': ' + itemResponses[2].getResponse() 
 + ' \n' + itemResponses[3].getItem().getTitle() + ': ' + itemResponses[3].getResponse()
 + ' \n' + itemResponses[4].getItem().getTitle() + ': ' + itemResponses[4].getResponse()
 + ' \n' + itemResponses[4].getItem().getTitle() + ': ' + itemResponses[4].getResponse()

    sendLineNotify(msg);

}
function sendLineNotify(message) {

var token = ["DdiU5tUykpSRpxRVqmEnM7ul3hcE3NEvc6Vzwknyzo7"];
var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "payload": "message=" + message,
    "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
    }
};

UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify", options);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you give more information on what are you trying to do?

Comment: i trying to make a form in which when summited it give a notification on Line app. the problem is that i want to attach my url on my spreadsheet onto the message but I don't know how to do it

Comment: What is that URL you want to attach?

Comment: The URL I want to attach is a google form edit URL

Comment: But what is exactly the issue? To get the url? To send it?

Comment: I want to get the URL

Comment: Since you already have the form ID you can form the edit URL by: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/FORMID/edit